# Cycle2 Prev/Next buttons not triggering cycles

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I'm trying to implement Cycle 2's Prev and Next buttons. The cycle is working - slides change every 5 secs - but I cannot get the prev and next buttons working.

My code is:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" id="prev" ></i>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" id="next" ></i>

<div id="sliderholder" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="fade" 
    data-cycle-timeout="5000"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev"
    data-cycle-next="#next"
    data-cycle-slides="> div">

      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give your i-tags a `z-index:101`, which lays them over the slides. Otherwise they disappear under the slides. To me it seems like a bug... I hope you get it working;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.carousel-main{
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
}
#sliderholder{
  z-index:-1;
}
.slide {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background:#000;
}
.slide1{
  background:green;
}
.slide2{
  background:blue;
}
.slide3{
  background:pink;
}
i{
  background:#fff;
  display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    top:calc( 50% - 10px );
    cursor:pointer;
}
#prev{
  left:0;
}
#next{
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-main">


<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" id="prev" > prev </i>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" id="next" > next</i>

<div id="sliderholder" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="fade" 
    data-cycle-timeout="5000"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev"
    data-cycle-next="#next"
    data-cycle-slides="> div">

      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Jsfiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/o2s54ctw/4/